# !important in mixins

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I have a function:

```
.box-shadow(@bxsh: none) {
    -moz-box-shadow: @bxsh;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @bxsh;
    box-shadow: @bxsh;
}
```

How to add !important to function parameter?
I right this:

```
.box-shadow(inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px 0 #fff !important;);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to never use `!important` :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to call the `!important` keyword after the mixin itsef, as [the documentation states](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-the-codeimportantcode-keyword).

```
.box-shadow(inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 1px 0 #fff) !important;
```

Additionally, you are attempting to call a mixin with two parameters, when it only accepts one.